# How to create .ics file using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, icalendar

[image]I used below code for creating .ics file but it's not working can any one help me,where its going wrong.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sbICSFile = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sbICSFile.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
sbICSFile.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
sbICSFile.AppendLine("PRODID:-//ICSTestCS/");
sbICSFile.AppendLine("CALSCALE:GREGORIAN");
sbICSFile.AppendLine("BEGIN:VTIMEZONE");

----------
----------
Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Test.ics");
Response.Write(sbICSFile);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly is not working?

Comment: Change `Response.Write(sbICSFile);` to `Response.Write(sbICSFile.ToString());` - you are sending the StringBuilder instance instead of the built string.

Comment: once create file i'm adding to calendar but it's showing could't open event it's possible the calendar file is corrupted

Comment: @Filburt What does writing an object do if not converting that object to a string and then writing the string?

Comment: I try Response.Write(sbICSFile.ToString()); also but still its not working

Comment: @amit If you download the file and open it in a decent text editor, what exactly do you get?

Comment: I am getting blank file there is no data

Comment: after adding Response.Write(sbICSFile.ToString()); i am getting my all data in decent text editor but still its not adding to calendar.

Comment: @amit - so the *creation* works now. Problem is the *adding* (assuming the actual content is correct; did you double check that? Not familiar with ics format.). How do you add?

Comment: Once download file i click on it and it's goes to my calendar there i'm getting error now

Comment: ... and that error is?

Comment: Couldn't open event. it's possible the calendar file is corrupted

Comment: Well, most likely, the file you create is not a valid [iCalendar](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2445). -- Does every `BEGIN` have a corresponding `END`? Could be a problem with `utf-8` encoding; as the documentation says: `"If a non-US-ASCII compatible character set is used, appropriate code-point from that character set MUST be chosen instead. Use of non-US-ASCII-compatible character sets is NOT recommended."`

Comment: Try building `sbICSFile` with a working example `iCalendar` (for example from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)). That way you'll know if everything else works and just the content itself is wrong.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is how I usually create `.ics` files.

```
//some variables for demo purposes
DateTime DateStart = DateTime.Now;
DateTime DateEnd = DateStart.AddMinutes(105);
string Summary = "Small summary text";
string Location = "Event location";
string Description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.";
string FileName = "CalendarItem";

//create a new stringbuilder instance
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//start the calendar item
sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
sb.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
sb.AppendLine("PRODID:stackoverflow.com");
sb.AppendLine("CALSCALE:GREGORIAN");
sb.AppendLine("METHOD:PUBLISH");

//create a time zone if needed, TZID to be used in the event itself
sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VTIMEZONE");
sb.AppendLine("TZID:Europe/Amsterdam");
sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:STANDARD");
sb.AppendLine("TZOFFSETTO:+0100");
sb.AppendLine("TZOFFSETFROM:+0100");
sb.AppendLine("END:STANDARD");
sb.AppendLine("END:VTIMEZONE");

//add the event
sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

//with time zone specified
sb.AppendLine("DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:" + DateStart.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm00"));
sb.AppendLine("DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:" + DateEnd.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm00"));
//or without
sb.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + DateStart.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm00"));
sb.AppendLine("DTEND:" + DateEnd.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm00"));

sb.AppendLine("SUMMARY:" + Summary + "");
sb.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + Location + "");
sb.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:" + Description + "");
sb.AppendLine("PRIORITY:3");
sb.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");

//end calendar item
sb.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

//create a string from the stringbuilder
string CalendarItem = sb.ToString();

//send the calendar item to the browser
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", CalendarItem.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + FileName + ".ics\"");
Response.Write(CalendarItem);
Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: thank you now i can able to add in calendar but there is one issue while adding in calendar its taking previous date, like i am passing today's date so its taking yesterday's date why its taking yesterday's date can you help me?

Comment: Check if the time zones are correct perhaps? Try with and without.

Comment: `string eventDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lblEventDate.Text).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm00Z");` i convert like this its working fine but i wanted only date, time should be 000000 how i can convert this?

Comment: You can do this: `DateStart.ToString("yyyyMMddT000000")` or `DateStart.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "T000000"`

Comment: `string eventDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lblEventDate.Text).Date.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm00Z");`



Note **.Date**

Comment: The use of string concatenation inside of a string builder just gave me a stroke.   Also, (Summary + "") ?  Good thing we add on that empty string for no reason but to increase memory usage.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the accepted answer, you must also add UID and DTSTAMP to work for google calendar.
Here’s what I added:

```
sb.AppendLine("UID:" + (Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm00")));
sb.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm00"));
```

You can also test your content [here](https://icalendar.org/validator.html).

Comment: Where do you add this?

Comment: You can add this immediately before the line that has END:VEVENT.

Answer (score 4):

I thrashed on building ics files that supported timezones.  I ended up going with [ical.Net](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net) to produce the files.  Their [wiki](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/wiki) has a basic example of how to produce the file.  Here is what it looks like when you need timezone support.

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now;
var endDate = startDate.AddHours(1);
var calendar = new Calendar
               {
                  Method = "PUBLISH",
               };
calendar.AddTimeZone("America/Chicago");
var calendarEvent = new CalendarEvent
        {
            Description = "Your description here",
            End = new CalDateTime(endDate, "America/Chicago"),
            Location = "Your location here",
            Start = new CalDateTime(startDate, "America/Chicago"),
            Summary = "Your summary here"
        };
calendar.Events.Add(calendarEvent);
```

Then to get the ics file as a string:

```
var serializer = new CalendarSerializer();
var iscFile = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
```

Finally I'd recommend validating your results with this [tool](https://icalendar.org/validator.html).
Hope that saves someone some time.